# Can't remove class from div

Tags: jquery, css

I am dynamically setting id's to divs from JSON. When I try to remove a class from some of those divs nothing happens.

```
if(dueDate < today){
    debtID = "#" + data[i].id_debt;
    console.log(debtID);
    $(debtID).removeClass(_this.hiddenClassAlt);
}
```

The console display #4. But on the div with id="4", it remains hidden.

If I do this:

```
if(dueDate < today){
    debtID = "#" + data[i].id_debt;
    $("#4").removeClass(_this.hiddenClassAlt);
}
```

That will work. I know it's something simple, but what am I missing?

EDIT: Here is additional code, maybe something is wrong somewhere else which is causing the class not to be removed. However, the console still display debtID as the correct div ID.

```
        for(var i = 0; i < debtsLength; i++){

            var debtID = '';

            if(data[i].dob != null){
                data[i].dob = _this.localPost.reformatDate(data[i].dob);
            }

            if(data[i].created_date !== null ){

                var dueDate = $.datepicker.parseDate( "yy-mm-dd", data[i].created_date);
                var today = new Date();

                dueDate = dueDate.toISOString();
                today = today.toISOString();

                data[i].created_date = _this.localPost.reformatDate(data[i].created_date);

                debtID = "#" + data[i].id_debt;
                //debtID = debtID.replace(/ /g,'');
            } else {
                var dueDate = null;
                var today = null;
            }

            if(data[i].update_date != null){
                data[i].update_date = _this.localPost.reformatDate(data[i].update_date);
            }

            output = Mustache.render(_this.accountDebtsTemplate, data[i]);

            if(dueDate < today){
                debtID = "#" + data[i].id_debt;
                console.log(debtID);
                $(debtID).removeClass(_this.hiddenClassAlt);
            }

            $(_this.debteeContainer).append(output);

            $(_this.showDebtee).addClass(_this.hiddenClassAlt);
            $(_this.hideDebtee).removeClass(_this.hiddenClassAlt);

        }
```

EDIT: Solved. I moved the if(dueDate < today) to the very end of the loop.

Thanks for the tips. I will also go ahead and change the id's to not start with a number.

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle?

Comment: data[i].id_debt what it returns in console or alert please check quick

Comment: maybe append quotes . Wild Guess

Comment: For HTML 4 a valid id should not start with a number (`#4` would be invalid). HTML is less fussy, but there are still a lot of HTML 4 browsers out there (e.g. IE < 10) :)

Comment: your code should work. check this http://jsfiddle.net/5nhCy/

Comment: With jsfiddle I can't reproduce it. I will include the entire for loop, maybe there is something wrong there.

Comment: data[i].id_debt returns 4.

Comment: I agree with @TrueBlueAussie ,don't name the id start with number.

Comment: I will go ahead and change the id's to not start with a number.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code in a fiddle with some changes but it works fine by me.

[Check this](http://jsfiddle.net/Callie_/r58fE/1/)

```
var dueDate = 0;
var today = 2;
var data = ["4"];
var i = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){
    if(dueDate < today){
        debtID = "#" + data[i];
        $(debtID).removeClass("testClass");
    }   
});
```

Maybe there is something wrong with the classname you put in .removeClass() ?